# Can I set the overlay of a Jquery modal dialog to a HTML page?

Tags: jquery, html

I was wondering if there is any way to set the overlay of my jQuery modal dialog to a HTML page.  I want [the modal dialog dialog] just to be good looking.

Comment: No, you will have to create this yourself.

Comment: did you google it first ?

Comment: Please try and format your question as good as you can and reread your question before posting, mr good looking John Oak.